How to Get BlockNumber by tx hash
I am new to solana , I am try to get block info by tx_hash
these are my codes:
let data = rpc.get_signatures_for_address_with_config(&program_id, config).unwrap();

for data in data {
            info!("signature:{:?}",&data.signature);
            let signature: Signature = Signature::from_str(&data.signature).unwrap();
            let transaction = rpc.get_transaction_with_config(&signature, RpcTransactionConfig {
                encoding: Some(UiTransactionEncoding::Json),
                commitment: None,
                max_supported_transaction_version: Some(0),
            }).unwrap();
            let meta=transaction.transaction.meta.unwrap();
}


This is slightly off topic, but for data in data doesn't quite make sense. If you wanted to iterate over data the singular would be datum or better yet a less vague name like confirmed_tranaction.

If I understand correctly, you have some signatures for transactions and want to find out what block they're in. get_signatures_for_address_with_config (the func you're using) returns a vec of RpcConfirmedTransactionStatusWithSignature. Using these, you can just do:
/// Assuming sig has type RpcConfirmedTransactionStatusWithSignature
let block = rpc.getBlock(sig.slot).unwrap();

This will return an instance of the following struct:
pub struct EncodedConfirmedBlock {
    pub previous_blockhash: String,
    pub blockhash: String,
    pub parent_slot: Slot,
    pub transactions: Vec<EncodedTransactionWithStatusMeta>,
    pub rewards: Rewards,
    pub block_time: Option<UnixTimestamp>,
    pub block_height: Option<u64>,
}

block_height is how many blocks precede this block, so your block number would be block_height + 1.
